# Python send keys on windows

Tags: python, winapi, sendkeys

I'm trying to send keyboard commands through python 2.7 on a windows machine. I understand that the SendKeys module does not work with 2.7. So I use keybd_event from the win32 api instead.

The key that i want to send is shift+left to select a word. This is the code:

```
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LSHIFT,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LEFT,0,0,0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LSHIFT,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)
```

This all works. However, the shift key stays depressed! Even after I kill the process. The only way to release the shift key after is to physically press capslock, then shift + a key, then capslock off. Its very similiar to this problem: http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-vb-RvVMlrAbZn/

Do you have any idea what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it's because you are passing in 0 as the scan code (the second parameter). Try calling `scanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_LSHIFT, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)` and passing that to the keybd_event method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried that with:
scanCode = win32api.MapVirtualKey(win32con.VK_LSHIFT, 0)
I set a zero there because i could not find MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC.
However, it still doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: What value is in scanCode after you call that?

Answer (score -1):

While i couldnt find a way to get win32api to work with shift, I'm using SendKeys from http://code.google.com/p/sendkeys-ctypes/ right now, which seems to work with 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

SendInput from the windows API may be helpful. The recent Raymond Chen blog entry suggests you can even use it to control screensaver start/stop.

Comment: Do you have any links for your references? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the [`pywin32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) package, please note it is old and unmaintained.

Here's [an example from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150966/simulating-keystrokes-in-python-using-pywin32)