# Simulating keystrokes in python using pywin32

Tags: python, user-interface, simulation

I am looking to simulate keystrokes in python 3.2 in windows 7 to be sent to a GUI.I have python win32 module installed on my pc.The order is alt+t+r+name+enter.What would be the best way of sending these keystrokes to the active window?any sample code would be of a great help.
Thanking you.
(I have seen some module called sendkeys but can that be used with pywin32?i am not allowed to install any other modules)

Answer (score 9):

I know this may not be perfect.  We have a testing application using python 2.7.  We leverage the windows scripting host to send keys.  I have not had time to port anything over to python 3, but this might get you in the right direction.  It should be pretty similar.

```
import win32api
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("app")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.AppActivate("myApp")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.SendKeys("%")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("t")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("r")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("name")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
win32api.Sleep(2500)
```

Here is a list of the [send key commands](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) for Windows Scripting Host.

## Update

This uses pywin32.  It is installed by default in the [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) version of python (which is the one I am using).  I am not sure, but I do not believe, that it is installed by default in the plain vanilla version of python.