# make a keyboard input command from a python script

Tags: python, io, keyboard

is there any way to make keyboard input from my program. suppose my program reeives "1" from a socket. how this data can be converted to a real time keyboard hit. means when "1" would receive , the computer would think that i pressed "1" .

Comment: Try to look into PyWin32, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150966/simulating-keystrokes-in-python-using-pywin32

Comment: That only works if windows is the intended target.  Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, you can use pywin32 to make a keypress. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136780/314013) previous answer for a code example.

In Linux, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576118/314013) previous answer has you covered, using xsendkey or xsendkeycode

And for Macs, [another previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6868212/314013) using PyQt or wxPython.

Comment: if i want to hold a key for 1second then , what method should i use? for this purpose

Comment: Which method are you using? Or what OS?

Comment: #python 2.7 in win7. sendkeys 0.3                                        import win32com.client
import time
import SendKeys
import os
from ctypes import *

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

os.startfile("E:/Projects/server-client socket/dist/test.exe")

time.sleep( 3 )

shell.SendKeys('h')
shell.SendKeys('4')     # i want to hold the 4 key for 1 sec

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput its cross-platform control for mouse and keyboard in python

Keyboard control works on X11(linux) and Windows systems. But no mac support as of now.

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()
k.tap_key(k.numpad_keys[1], n=1)  # Tap 1 on the numpad once.
```